# Debian buster upgrade renamed all interfaces to renameX

Tags: debian, networking

Prior to upgrade they were named like:

```
iface ens2f0
iface ens2f1
```

from original install. Now they are like:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: rename2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:67:7c:84:2b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:67:7c:84:2c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: rename4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:67:7c:84:2d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: rename5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:1e:67:7c:84:2e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

They are Intel gigabit I350 adapters, so from lshw I have:

```
           *-network:0 DISABLED
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
            logical name: rename2
            version: 01
            serial: 00:1e:67:7c:84:2b
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.48, 0x800006e7 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
            resources: irq:26 memory:d0960000-d097ffff ioport:2060(size=32) memory:d09b0000-d09b3fff memory:d0aa0000-d0abffff memory:d0a80000-d0a9ffff
       *-network:1 DISABLED
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: I350 Gigabit Network Connection
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0.1
            bus info: pci@0000:02:00.1
            logical name: eno0
            version: 01
            serial: 00:1e:67:7c:84:2c
            size: 1Gbit/s
            capacity: 1Gbit/s
            width: 32 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.4.0-k duplex=full firmware=1.48, 0x800006e7 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
            resources: irq:39 memory:d0940000-d095ffff ioport:2040(size=32) memory:d09a0000-d09a3fff memory:d0a60000-d0a7ffff memory:d0a40000-d0a5ffff
       *-network:2 DISABLED
            ...
```

I have installed firmware-linux-nonfree in case it was an firmware issue, but it worked fine on Debian Stretch. I don't understand how the logical names are/should be created here. I guess I could configure int rename2 as a static IP and just use it? Why is one named eno0 now? All four interfaces show disabled in lshw.

Edit: added more detail

I have also asked udevadmin what it thought:

```
udevadm test-builtin net_id /sys/class/net/eno0 2>/dev/null
ID_NET_NAMING_SCHEME=v240
ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx001e677c842c
ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Intel Corporate
ID_NET_NAME_ONBOARD=eno0
ID_NET_LABEL_ONBOARD=enPowerVille
ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp2s0f1
ID_NET_NAME_SLOT=ens2f1
```

So why doesn't Debian see that interface as ens2f1 instead of eno0?

Edit 2: added solution from @telcoM

```
vi /etc/systemd/network/20-builtins.link 
 [Match]
 Path=pci-0000:02:*

 [Link]
 NamePolicy=slot
```

Then restart and I get:

```
kernel: [  107.897834] igb 0000:02:00.1 ens2f1: igb: ens2f1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
Mar 30 11:56:45 host1 kernel: [  107.897978] br1: port 1(ens2f1) entered blocking state
Mar 30 11:56:45 host1 kernel: [  107.897981] br1: port 1(ens2f1) entered forwarding state
Mar 30 11:56:45 host1 kernel: [  107.898129] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): br1: link becomes ready
Mar 30 11:56:46 host1 kernel: [  108.093815] igb 0000:02:00.0 ens2f0: igb: ens2f0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: RX
Mar 30 11:56:46 host1 kernel: [  108.093957] br0: port 1(ens2f0) entered blocking state
Mar 30 11:56:46 host1 kernel: [  108.093960] br0: port 1(ens2f0) entered forwarding state
```

I still get errors on boot bringing network up, can't find specific error in syslog, but my interfaces and bridges are up now! Thanks a lot @telcoM

Comment: You can use the ip command to rename them to anything you want - see  https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=109057.

Comment: Yes, but why doesn't Debian see them and name them per normal ensp#s# schema, and why does it show them disabled?

Comment: Regarding why they're list as disabled, it's probably because the interfaces are down. You can't bring up an interface with the incorrect device name on a reboot. Just edit the  device names with the correct device names in /etc/network/interaces . Then you can change the names later to whatever you like later.  If you have further questions, post the interface file and the output of "ifconfig -a".  Make a backup copy of the interaces file before you edit it,

Comment: I was able (until I do more debug) to change iface names in /etc/network/interfaces to rename2, etc. and it did bring the interfaces up, so now I can focus on the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Network interface names like `rename2` indicate that the system was in the process of renaming the interfaces, but ran into a conflict somehow.

Check `/etc/udev/rules.d` for old Stretch-era udev rules for NIC naming, and comment them out or remove them altogether if possible. Also check for any applicable `/etc/systemd/network/*.link` files: those would be the newest way to assign names for the NICs.

Names like `eno0` are based on firmware information (DMI data perhaps?) that identifies the "physical" numbering of built-in network interfaces: apparently your system firmware says that the NIC with PCI path `0000:02:00.1` is labeled as "0th" in your system board.

I've understood that the `enoX` naming should start at `eno1` and the numbers should go up from there. `eno0` might be a firmware definition bug: perhaps your current system firmware says that the network interface is built-in, but the number of the interface is left undefined. If the same is true on two or more NICs, then the system will be trying to name multiple interfaces as `eno0` which is not going to work.

You could override the naming scheme by creating a file `/etc/systemd/network/20-builtins.link` with the following contents:

```
[Match]
Path=pci-0000:02:*

[Link]
NamePolicy=slot
```

If the two other interfaces have their PCI paths as something other than `0000:02:*.*`, then you might want to adjust the `Path=` line so that it matches them all. This should tell the system to stop trying to assign `en0`-style "built-in NIC" names, and use the slot-style names that were used before.

Answer (score 1):

I see this same behaviour with Red Hat EL when moving from production versions to the beta  test version of 9. It looks like the difference in behaviour is down to the version of systemd being used.

The question is really why the older version used to give names like enp2f0 rather than eno0. Without seeing the output of `dmidecode -t 9` to see the SMBIOS records for the PCI slots on the system I can't explain why the original poster was seeing names like ens2f0 which implies that SMBIOS is showing the onboard device as also have a physical slot number.

I tracked down why the name `eno0` wasn't being returned in older versions of `systemd`, such as I was used to. The function `dev_pci_onboard` was checking for values <= 0 and returning an error. Newer version have more complex logic in here and systemd 250 does accept the instance number of 0 returned by SMBIOS. So to answer the original question, I guess it has switched from returning the `enp` style name after an update as `systemd` is now accepting the data from the FW.

This is an update to a reply I made yesterday.

The `eno` style names are used when either SMBIOS (DMI) or ACPI return information showing the device to be an onboard NIC. I've never dug into the ACPI case but for the SMBIOS case it is the type 41 records which supersede the older type 10 records. See examples below.

For older versions of `systemd` the function `dev_pci_onboard` in `udev/udev-builtin-net_id.c` checks the returned index number with `<= 0` and then returns an error, so if your do a `dmidecode -t 41` and see the `Type Instance` of 0 then these older versions of systemd were ignoring SMBIOS and therefore falling through to using the `ens` or `enp` style names with the PCI slot or address.
With systemd 250 the logic in the function is more complex but it means that it can accept SMBIOS device instances numbers of 0.

The below is the posting I wrote yesterday before I discovered all this but it shows where the data comes from and has a general comment about the SMBIOS instance numbers.

I see the same behaviour on Red Hat, I'd be interested as to why firmware instance numbers for devices are supposed to start at 1.
One place that the numbers for the `eno` style names can come from are from the SMBIOS (DMI) type 41 records.

```
[root@ml110c ~]# dmidecode -t 41
# dmidecode 3.2

Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.6 present.

Handle 0x2900, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
        Reference Designation: NIC Port 1
        Type: Ethernet
        Status: Enabled
        Type Instance: 0
        Bus Address: 0000:02:00.0

Handle 0x2901, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
        Reference Designation: NIC Port 2
        Type: Ethernet
        Status: Enabled
        Type Instance: 1
        Bus Address: 0000:03:00.0

[root@ml110c ~]#
```

On this system, an HP ProLiant ml110 g7 the instance numbers for the NIC ports are 0 and 1. The NIC port 2 has an instance number of 1 and gets assigned the "predictable name" of `eno1`. But the device with the instance number of 0 ends up being called `enp2s0` as there is no type 9 record for this PCI address.

```
[root@ml110c ~]# ethtool -i enp2s0
driver: e1000e
version: 3.2.6-k
firmware-version: 2.1-2
expansion-rom-version:
bus-info: 0000:02:00.0
supports-statistics: yes
supports-test: yes
supports-eeprom-access: yes
supports-register-dump: yes
supports-priv-flags: no
[root@ml110c ~]#
```

note the PCI address, this is the device identified by the first type 41 record.

On HP gen9 servers with 10G NICs the onboard device instance numbers start at 49 rather than 1, various postings online suggest the same is true for some Dell servers. On the HP machines I have access to these NICs show up with "predictable names" of `eno49`, `eno50` ... I'm not sure how I'm suppose to be able to predict these names. The newer gen10 HPE servers don't do this and they start at `eno1`.